# How many disputed and undisputed Torah Mitzvot are there?

Tags: number, jewish-books, mitzvah

If you combine all the known lists of the "613 Mitzvot" (Rambam, Ramban, Semag, etc.), how many total mitzvot are listed by at least one person as a Mitzvah Deoreitya?

I am curious to compare this to other countings of halachot.

Comment: This is one of a group of similar questions: [_mitzvos_](http://yodeya.com/q/34253), [_Mishna_](http://yodeya.com/q/34224), [_Y'rushalmi_](http://yodeya.com/q/34254), [_Bavli_](http://yodeya.com/q/34252), [_Mishne Tora_](http://yodeya.com/q/34248), [_Shulchan Aruch_](http://yodeya.com/q/34249), [_Mishna B'rura_](http://yodeya.com/q/34251),  [_Yalkut Yosef_](http://yodeya.com/q/34250)

Comment: FYI I'm (slowly) working on a database and website which will contain this data. So far done Rambam Ramban, Semag, and Chinuch. Stay tuned. Of those four they agree to ~530 mitzvos. It gets worse when you include Rav Saadiah Gaon, who disagrees on over 200 mitzvos with the Rambam.